# Unusual table output from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Why am I getting those extra layers in the table output? I need to remove those extra layers from the table.What am I doing wrong? What is going on here exactly? Updated code.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "cop");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql= mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT FirstName, Practice FROM Members");

echo "
    <style>th {
    font: bold 11px 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    color: #6D929B;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    background: #CAE8EA url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}

th.nobg {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    background: none;
}</style>


<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>FirstName</th>
<th>Practice</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Practice'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

[Unusual Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUHsi.png)

Comment: The extra layers are the empty rows in your html table ?  update your question and add your sql code  ..

Comment: Do you have null rows in the query result?

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement please?

Comment: I added the remaining sql code

Comment: check the table in the mysql database if it has any empty row

Comment: @fortune Nope..all my rows are filled

Comment: YEs!! one empty row but it was barely seeable..thanks!

Comment: there must be 2 empty rows. Check that.

Comment: Can you also add the primary key value as first column in your html table so that you can debug it quickly. It should print the id in the first column if there is one in the db

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do something like this you would be able to tell if there were empty column values in the data

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) ){

    if( !empty( $row['FirstName'] ) && !empty( $row['Practice'] ) ){
        $firstname=$row['FirstName'];
        $practice=$row['Practice'];
    } else{
        $firstname=$practice='empty';
    }

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>{$firstname}</td>
            <td>{$practice}</td>
        </tr>";

}
```

Alternatively just output the row if it is known to contain values rather than having empty cells

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) ){

    if( !empty( $row['FirstName'] ) && !empty( $row['Practice'] ) ){
        $firstname=$row['FirstName'];
        $practice=$row['Practice'];
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$firstname}</td>
                <td>{$practice}</td>
            </tr>";     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code on my Notepad++ and in it were errors which the browser cannot forgive. In fact you can even receive a 1 month suspended sentence from your browser. Below is my version of your code. I have ignored the style. You can add style after the code is working.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "cop");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FirstName, Practice FROM Members");

$result = '';

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 

$FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
$Practice  = $row['Practice'];

$result .= "<tr><td>" . $FirstName . "</td><td>" . $Practice . "</td></tr>";

    }

}

if(isset($result)){

echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr><th>FirstName</th><th>Practice</th></tr>";

echo $result;

echo "</table>";

}

?>
```